# Stepped graph in Android application

Tags: android, graph

I want to create a stepped graph in an Android native application.

The graph should generate in two ways:

1. from the mobile manually(like ON state, OFF state)
2. from the ELD automatically

Both data should sync and generate an accurate single-stepped graph. The data will be saved later in a database.

[I found this code snippet but it is web code; how can we do the same thing in native Android?](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart)

I want this kind of graph:

[image: I want this kind of graph]

I want This kind of graph , This graph have 4 sides data

LEFT) ON & OFF state

TOP) 24 hours time

RIGHT) total time of each state

BOTTOM) serial number for state

I found [some](https://github.com/appsthatmatter/GraphView) [libraries](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Please any one suggest me how to make it happen.

Comment: Did u achieve this?